# c++ pointer and index change places

Tags: c++, pointers

I found this code on the Internet and was wondering how does it work?

```
int m[10]; //array with 10 elements
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    m[i] = i; //simple initializing

int* a = &m[0]; //a - pointer at the first array's element

3[a] = 20; //???

for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    cout << m[i] << endl;//out
```

As you can guess the output is:

```
0
1
2
20
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `a[b]` is equivalent to `b[a]` similarly to how `a + b` is the same as `b + a`.

`a[3]` will go `3` addresses forward in memory from a.
`3[a]` will go `a` addresses forward in memory from 3.

See how that works? ;) (Of course, this only works for pointers because they are memory addresses)

Comment: What do you mean by "`a` addresses forward from 3"? `a` isn't a number, and 3 isn't an address, so that makes no sense. It works because `[]` is defined in terms of addition, and addition is commutative.

Comment: I know I'm technically wrong, but I found it more intuitive to explain it with this tiny abstraction. I apologize for the confusion I may have caused

Answer (score 6):

When one of `a` and `b` is a pointer and the other and integer, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`. As addition is commutative, that is the same as `*(b + a)`, which, from the definition of `[]`, is the same as `b[a]`.